# How do I add the complex numbers $z^4$ and $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers

This question is similar to a question I posted earlier.
$$z=\cos\frac{\pi}{3}+j\sin\frac{\pi}{3}$$

This time I have to do the sum $z^4+z$

I have used the approach I was shown in my previous question. Here is what I've done:
$$\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{3}+j\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^4+\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{3}+j\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$\cos\frac{4 \pi}{3}+j\sin\frac{4 \pi}{3}+\cos\frac{\pi}{3}+j\sin\frac{\pi}{3}$$
collecting like terms...
$$\cos\frac{5\pi}{3}+2j\sin\frac{5\pi}{3}$$
I verified this with wolframalpha but the answer it gave was zero. Is this approach I'm using appropriate for this problem?

Comment: Note that $\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)+\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\color{red}\neq\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)$

Comment: Alternatively, using that [$\,z^3=-1\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2770863/291201) it follows that $\,z+z^4=z(z^3+1)=0\,$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $0$ because$$\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)=\cos\left(\pi+\frac\pi3\right)=-\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\text{ and }\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)=\sin\left(\pi+\frac\pi3\right)=-\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Via de Moivre's Theorem, $z^4=\cos\big(\frac{4\pi}{3}\big)+j\sin\big(\frac{4\pi}{3}
\big)=-\frac{1}{2} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}j$
$$\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}}+j\sin{\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}j$$

Adding those together yields $0$.